# Test Spring startup with spock

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, integration-testing, spock

I am currently trying to test the application to start up correctly when a property is set.
Basically a test of the configuration and autowiring. I do NOT want to execute any bean, just want to start up the system.

My attempt with groovy 2.5.8 and spock 1.3-groovy2.5:

```
@ActiveProfiles([MY_PROFILES])
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = [Application], properties = ["property.enabled=true"])
class IntegrationTest extends Specification {

  def "Service starts up with property enabled"() {
    expect:
    noExceptionThrown()
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the following compile error:
`Error:(23, 5) Groovyc: Exception conditions are only allowed in 'then' blocks`

Does anybody have an idea how else I can achieve this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `noExceptionThrown` should help.
This should work:

```
  def "Service starts up with property enabled"() {
    expect: "All beans are created"
  }
```